# WordPress api returns distinct data

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a restful api for wordpress blog. In a url I'm returning the details of categories of that blog. The same api returns array in one blog and object in another.

The code is-

```
function categories(){
    $categories = get_categories(array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
    ));
    return $categories;
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function ( $server ) {
    $server->register_route( 'categories', '/categories', array(
        'methods'  => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'categories',
    ));
});
```

Here is the output-

Blog 1

[image]

Blog 2

[image]

I need same type of data to be returned, so that I can further process that data.

Comment: Are the blogs having the same WP version?

Comment: the 2 sites are on the same WordPress version and with the same plugins ?

Comment: Yes the wordpress version is same and both sites have same plugin..

Answer (score 0):

Advise you to please check you categories result set for both the blogs, you will be able to find the difference, In blog 1 result set something might be missing when you are preparing array for json_encode. I use to face a lot of problems like this when I started developing REST API.
If problem still exist then please post both resultsets, so that we can identify.